# Can anyone confirm my (eulers method) implementation of these ordinary differential equations?

Tags: c, math, ode

[image]

I'm trying to implement these equations (Matsuoka's oscillator- details here http://www.ecila.org/ecila_files/content/papers/ACEICMC05.pdf) in C using Euler's method. I realise Euler isn't the most accurate method but it removes some complexity while I'm developing, and once I have this working I plan to switch to Runge Kutta. 
This is my implementation, but I can't replicate the results in the paper, so I'm sure I have something wrong. But no matter how many times I've looked over the code I can't find it.

Is anyone able to take a look over this code and confirm my working, or spot any errors?

```
#define POSPART(X)  X > 0.0 ? X : 0.0

double matsuoka_calc_nextVal(double in, double t1, double t2,
                          double c, double b, double g,
                          double *x1, double *x2,
                          double *v1, double *v2, double step)
{
    double posX1 = POSPART(*x1); 
    double posX2 = POSPART(*x2);
    double posIn = POSPART(in);


    // calculate derivatives
    double dx1 = (c - *x1 - (b*(*v1)) - (g*posX2) - posIn) / t1;
    double dx2 = (c - *x2 - (b*(*v2)) - (g*posX1) - posIn) / t1;
    double dv1 = (posX1 - *v1) / t2;
    double dv2 = (posX2 - *v2) / t2;

    // increment value by 1 euler step (using eulerStep =0.2 in testing)
    *x1 += dx1 * eulerStep;         
    *x2 += dx2 * eulerStep;
    *v1 += dv1 * eulerStep;         
    *v2 += dv2 * eulerStep;
    return POSPART(*x1) - POSPART(*x2);

}
```

Comment: Not reading the formula nor the pdf, The usage of macro `POSPART(*x1) - POSPART(*x2)` may be wrong. Is it OK for `POSPART(1.0) - POSPART(1.0)` to be `1.0`?

Comment: It is good to use parenthesis when defining function-like macro. i.e. `#define POSPART(X)  ((X) > 0.0 ? (X) : 0.0)`

Comment: AGH! yes, you're right that's definitely going to be wrong and there's a good chance that could be the source of all the error. How stupid. Thanks. I'll confirm when I'm back at my desk. Actually that makes sense of the weird results too - that I'm losing the values below 0 in most parameter spaces...

Comment: Mike - yes, thanks for this, this fixed the problem. If you want the rep post as an answer and I'll mark it as the chosen answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The defintion of macro

```
#define POSPART(X)  X > 0.0 ? X : 0.0
```

is wrong.

For example, if you write

```
POSPART(1.0) - POSPART(1.0)
```

this is expanded as

```
1.0 > 0.0 ? 1.0 : 0.0 - 1.0 > 0.0 ? 1.0 : 0.0
```

this is equivalent to

```
(1.0 > 0.0) ? 1.0 : (((0.0 - 1.0) > 0.0) ? 1.0 : 0.0)
```

as a result, `POSPART(1.0) - POSPART(1.0)` is evaluated as `1.0` because `1.0 > 0.0` is true.

To avoid troubles like this, you should enclose arguments and the whole expression of function-style macro like this:

```
#define POSPART(X)  ((X) > 0.0 ? (X) : 0.0)
```

In this case this should work, but something like `POSPART(x += 1.0)` won't work well because `x += 1.0` may be evaluated twice.
Functions should be used in this case.